# UsernameToken and BinarySecurityToken in the same services

Tags: web-services, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I have a new requirement but I don’t know how to develop it or if it’s possible or not, the problem is that my application has a web server but the client wants to call it with two different security policy, sometimes call it with UsernameToken and sometimes with  BinarySecurityToken.

The headers that the client will send are:

For UsernameToken

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASS</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Qm2Ytc9hW/xsQSo4KAurSQ==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2012-03-27T07:27:02.605Z</wsu:Created>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

And for BinarySecurityToken

```
   <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary" ValueType="esquema" wsu:Id="SSOToken" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">MEEwNjJFNTU3QzN....G13eWo5RT0=</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

So for UsernameToken I use this code in services.xml .. and it work fine, in PWCBHandler I get the username and password and I validate it against database.

```
<module ref="rampart" />
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
        <wsp:ExactlyOne>
            <wsp:All>
                <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:SupportingTokens>
                <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
                    <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>com.aaa.bbb.ccc.impl.PWCBHandler</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
                </ramp:RampartConfig>

            </wsp:All>
            <wsp:All/>
        </wsp:ExactlyOne>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

The problem is that I don’t know how to implement the security for BinarySecurityToken, in order to get the base64 string and do whatever I want with it, and the other doubt is that I don’t know if I can combine two security policies in the same service or should I to expose another one.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal of way of applying multiple security policies to the same service is through policy alternatives. But currently this is not supported in Axis2/Rampart.

But as a workaround, different policies can be engaged to different bindings of the same service. This blog post explains how to apply different policies to the same service.

http://blog.rampartfaq.com/2009/08/how-to-add-secured-and-non-secured-end.html

About the question on a policy on binary security tokens :

Binary security tokens are defined in WS-Security to transfer different types of tokens like X.509, Kerberos, non-XML tokens encoded in a certain format. So it is a generic element defined to embed different types of tokens within a SOAP message.